# Need help - Replacing DIV content with data from DB without refresh (using - jquery, hmlhttp, CI)

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

Here I go again. I am trying to change content of a division with data retrieved from my database. This has to be done without reloading the page, therefore I am using xmlhttp and javascript. The website is running on CodeIgniter. Below is the code with a short summary of it. I have been following [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp), but for some reason, when I click the button, nothing is happening.

**View** *xampInstallFolder/htdocs/application/obs/views/test_v.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      $( "#next_btn" ).click(function() {

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
      else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
          document.getElementById("listA").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
        }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","getnext5.php?q="true);
      xmlhttp.send();
      })
    </script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="listA">
  </div>

  <div id="next_btn">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Right now I trigger the function when my button gets clicked. The function is in the head of the view,. I am not sure where should the file with the query (`getnext5.php`) be stored. Right now it is inside the `views` folder. The link to the file is this `xmlhttp.open("GET","getnext5.php?q="true);` should I somehow change this?

**Functions** *xampInstallFolder/htdocs/application/obs/views/getnext5.php*

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','obs2');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"obs2");
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id > 5";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
        echo "<a style="display:block" href="base_url('core/detail/'.$row[id])">";
            echo "<div id="suggested" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">";
                echo "<div id="info">";
                    echo "<div id="info_center">";
                        echo "<p>" . $row['name'] . "</p>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";

                echo "<div class="mosaic-block fade">";
                    echo "<a href="base_url('core/detail/'.$row[id])" class="mosaic-overlay">";

                        echo '<div class="details">';
                            echo "<p>" . $row['summary'] . "</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</a>";

                    echo "<div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="www.puu.sh/5DSWj.jpg">";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";

                echo "<div id="info">";
                    echo "<div id="info_center">";
                        echo "<p>" . "Rating: 7.7" . "</p>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</a>";   

  }
echo "</table>";

?>
```

In this file I establish the connection to my DB, run the query, store the rows in an array called `$pages` and then style the results using a while loop. The style is echoed, because it is then returned by the xmlhttp request and displayed in the `listA` division, replacing the original content. I am not sure if the echoes are written right or not.

I am open to any suggestions. Have been trying to resolve this the whole day without any success.
Thank you all for reading and most importantly for your replies.

Comment: Since you're referencing jquery in this project, you should look into the jquery ajax api - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You're not concatenating the get parameter properly.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getnext5.php?q="true);
```

`q="true` <-- true is a boolean!

Try opening like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getnext5.php?q=true");
```

If you do want to concatenate proper, do `"q="+variable`

Comment: I do not have any variable that I am trying to pass. should I just make it `("GET","getnext5.php");` then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery ajax api, and then on success function you can replace div content with values retrieved from db.